# How to export report to HTML file with inline CSS in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: html, css, sas, enterprise-guide

When exporting a report in SAS Enterprise Guide to HTML file, CSS is created separately. 
I want to mail this html file in SAS, but it needs to include css also.

Is there any way to embed css style into html in Enterprise Guide?

P.S. I'm using htmlblue.css

Comment: Are you trying to use a style sheet or do you want to customize the output somehow. There's a CSSSTyle option available on several ODS statements.

Comment: I'm trying to include already made by SAS css style sheet into HTML as inline style. And is there a way to do it not by code?) I'm doing everything in GUI :)

Comment: Definitely only going to be via code but I'll look into it a bit more. Had tried this at one point a few years ago but wasn't possible then maybe now with HTML. Not sure what you're trying to customize but there's likely a way to do it using other options if you have flexibility.